# Passing multiple variables to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function, datatables

I have a big table of info which can get a bit overwhelming. I currently have buttons to hide or show certain columns to make it easier to find what you need. I use this code to show/hide.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    
function fnShowHide( iCol )
    {
        var oTable = $('#tablename').dataTable();
        var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
        oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
    }
</script>
```

Later on, I use the following code to hide or show a certain column in the table.

```
<button id="button">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(0);">Column1</a>
</button>
<button id="button">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(1);">Column2</a>
</button>
<button id="button">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(2);">Column3</a>
</button>
```

How would I make a single button that would hide or show multiple rows rather than just single rows?

I am using [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net) to show my data and am using [this](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/show_hide.html) example for the button above (if that makes a difference).

Comment: how about passing an array into the JS function?

Comment: Hi, according to you code, I think you not to hide/show some columns not rows, isn't it?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor That would probably work. The problem is that I'm a complete beginner and am not sure how to do that. I'll give it a google now.

Comment: @OQJF Nice spot. I meant Columns, but I will be using this same thing to hide rows later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than accepting a single integer as input, why not accept an array of rows you want to hide?

```
function fnShowHide( iCols )
{
    var i, iCol;
    var oTable = $('#tablename').dataTable();

    for (i = 0; i < iCols.length; i += 1) {
        iCol = iCols[i];
        var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
        oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
    }
}
```

To invoke it for one row you would just use `fnShowHide([2])`, and for multiple rows you would pass in multiple values like `fnShowHide([2,3,4])`

Comment: Buddy, just kind of curious, why you use i+=1, not i++?

Comment: Ah it's habbit from using a JavaScript linter. Either is fine.

Comment: Wait. You should check if the `iCols` is a valid array or not.

Comment: @fuzic EXCELLENT. This is exactly what I was looking to do, but I didn't have enough Javascript knowledge to get it to work. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Cully  You should probably select this as the answer, since it definitely seems to solve your question :)

Comment: @DavidL Yeah I always do thanks. It wouldn't let me earlier as it was too quick, but done now.